# Grub (debian) will not start in AHCI mode

Tags: debian, hard-disk, grub, hardware, boot-loader

I was running my Debian (Acer laptop) for quite some time without much trouble. However, when I started it recently I've got message:

```
No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key
```

It works with live cd (xubuntu) and hard drive is visible (I was able to do a little backup from live cd).
After searching Internet, I have switched in BIOS AHCI mode for IDE mode - and it works, however performance is much lower, and sometimes, when for example I have browser open and files are being copied, I am getting input/output error and need to do hard reset.
Can it be damaged HDD or it is more like system issue?
Maybe it will help:

```
dmesg | grep -iE 'err|warn|fail|fatal'
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    1.142728] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    1.580327] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    1.810972] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 *10 12 14 15)
[    1.811037] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 *11 12 14 15)
[    1.811099] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 10 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    1.811161] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 11 12 14 15) *10
[    1.811222] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 10 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    1.811285] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 *11 12 14 15)
[    1.811347] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 *10 12 14 15)
[    1.811409] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 7 *11 12 14 15)
[    1.811444] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[    4.027771] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[    4.035765] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   14.020286] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.020299] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.020305] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.020309] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053F (\_SB_.PCI0.GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.020314] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.020317] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053F (\_SB_.PCI0.GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   14.068599] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   14.828072] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000004000-0x000000000000401F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000004000-0x000000000000400F (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[   41.539932] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.539995] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540056] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540105] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540138] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540170] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540264] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   41.540298] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.VGA_._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[   54.063360] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1905 at /build/linux-zbOcpU/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/net/wireless/sme.c:920 cfg80211_connect+0x4aa/0x4f0 [cfg80211]()
[   54.063460]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[   54.070138] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1906 at /build/linux-zbOcpU/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/net/wireless/sme.c:920 cfg80211_connect+0x4aa/0x4f0 [cfg80211]()
[   54.070290]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
[   64.094209] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1903 at /build/linux-zbOcpU/linux-3.16.7-ckt25/net/wireless/sme.c:920 cfg80211_connect+0x4aa/0x4f0 [cfg80211]()
[   64.094309]  [<ffffffff810677f7>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x77/0x90
```

Answer (score 0):

typically the live cd's work better as they don't use all the functionality of the machine, they are more self sufficient packages.

start off by switching off acpi with a boot time param, then check your dsdt's.